# read_html not finding all rows from table

Tags: python, html, pandas

i'm trying to parse an html table using pandas `read_html` function.

I've discovered that the `head` method removes the last row for some reason so i stopped using it.

But now i've noticed that although visible though the debugger (as a string), another row is removed. So with `head` i'd have 5/7 (rows) and 6/7 (rows) without.

This is my current code:

```
r = get(f"site-censured").text
df = read_html(r)[0]
```

I'm accessing the values as if df is a matrix, so like df[2][3].

Am i doing something wrong?

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Ciao Alberto and welcome on SO.  It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating and testing the mcve, i've discovered the error. I've been looping from 1 to `df.shape[1]` which would result in the last row being ignored, so i just needed to add +1.
Thanks [rpanai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4819376/rpanai) for the suggestion